# How to convert pdf to text file using vba but not using acrobat library

Tags: excel, vba

**Would you please explain me on how to convert pdf file to text file using vba but not using acrobat libraries. As Acrobat libraries are not installed in my system, I am seeking alternative way. Thank You**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't an office object that supports the conversion of PDF to text. Alternatively you could write it in python using a conversion package ie tesseract and then access excel through openpyxl.